# How to play .wmv file with a MSS1 stream encoded?

Tags: encoding, video

Just wondering if anyone know how to play .wmv file with a MSS1 stream encoded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [MPlayerX](http://mplayerx.org/download.html) Version 1.0.17, better support for WMV than VLC (MMS1 is ok for me).

Answer (score 1):

According to [this discussion](http://www.geekzone.co.nz/forums.asp?forumid=45&topicid=96256), you may be able to play MSS1-encoded movies with [MPlayer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mplayer-ww/) (Windows only). If you can wait a little while longer, VLC [should gain](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?p=343251) the ability to play them in version 2.1. With VLC 2.0.3, I can at least hear the soundtrack (Codec *ACELP (Sipro)*).